# Sequelize error on npm start

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to implement sequelize on my project and when I put

```
var models = require('../models')
```

on bin/www, on npm start I get this error:

module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\projeto\models/..configconfig.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\projeto\models\index.js:8:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\projeto\bin\www:10:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! projeto@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the projeto@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the projeto package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs projeto
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls projeto
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\Desktop\projeto\npm-debug.log
```

Besides the default dependencies on a project created with express, I added these:

```
  "pg": "^7.0.2",
  "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
  "sequelize": "^4.4.2",
  "sequelize-cli": "^2.7.0"
```

Obs:
npm install/update didn't solve the problem
reinstall node.js didn't solve the problem
create a new project didn't solve the problem

does anyone have an idea of how to solve this?

thanks a lot!

@Edit
This is my full package.json

```
{
  "name": "projeto",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {

    "sequelize": "^4.4.2",
    "sequelize-cli": "^2.7.0",
    "pg": "^7.0.2",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "body-parser": "~1.17.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.3",
    "ejs": "~2.5.6",
    "express": "~4.15.2",
    "morgan": "~1.8.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.2"

  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your folder structure and full package.json?

Comment: I have doubts on path models/..configconfig.json. Do you have configconfig.json or you just missed a slash

Comment: I don't have that file, i'm not sure where the error is coming from, I just added the var models = require('../models') and the error began

Answer (score 1):

In your models *index.js* file change the following line:

```
var config = require(__dirname + '/..\config\config.json')[env];
```

to:

```
var config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
```